# How to prevent bones from transforming between frame 1 and frame 2

Tags: armature, bones, physics, constraints, rigid-body-simulation

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUmIKWVrHZU) for creating a ragdoll in blender. It basically says to delete parents from all bones in a rig, then create cubes (colliders for the ragdoll) with rigid body physics enabled, use the *child of* bone constraint to parent bones to their colliders and then put rigid body constraints in places where joints should be.

The ragdoll works great but I ran into a small issue. Between frame 1 and 2 of the animation, the bones in the rig transform in weird ways, some move, some flip, some rotate. I tried to look for any similar issue on the web but couldn't find anything.

I would be really grateful if anyone told me what I did wrong and how to solve it even if it meant redoing the ragdoll from scratch.

[image]

[image: You can see the bones moving generally closer, but also notice how some bones from the spine and legs flip]

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots Oh sorry, I'm new to this forum and didn't know you had to do this. I just uploaded the file.

Comment: it looks like there's a problem of transform (scale), but if you apply the scale it looks like it will mess up the whole thing, there may be a way to correct that, or do it again but this time apply the scale of your objects? I hope someone will answer in detail...